# How to jump to super implementation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Given the code segment:

```
@Override
public String someMethod()
{
  return "foo";
}
```

Is there a way in Eclipse to quickly jump to the implementation in super?  Since it's annotated with @Override, I would think Eclipse would know how to do this.

For now as a clunky work-around, I'll type in "super.someMethod();" as the first line (even though I don't need it), click on the method name on that line, and hit F3.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.1 (Ganymede) for Solaris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a little hollow arrow on the left of the method invocation line for the implementation of an interface method, and a little solid arrow on the left of the method invocation line for the implementation of a method override.

Left clicking on the hollow arrow takes you to the interface method.

Left clicking on the solid arrow takes you to the method that's overridden.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the shortcut key: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + N, S

Comment: Though i't's not a real hotkey (it opens menu, etc.) this one is the closest to what I was looking for. It would be great to have a real hot key for such operation.

Comment: @PuterdoBorato you can define your own custom 1-key shortcut using in `Preferences>Keys>Open Super Implementation`

Answer (score 4):

I like Alt+N, S as Reimeus wrote.  Another option that doesn't require your cursor to be in the function in question is to use the pop-up outline view:

- `Ctrl-O` to open outline
- `Ctrl-O` to show inherited members
- Type method name to find it

Answer (score 2):

Yes: Hover over the method name, hold CTRL, and select "Open Super Implementation" from the menu that appears